# making index of video files

Tags: python, video

I have several directories of video files (Windows) in various formats (avi, mp2, asf, ...) and want to get a listing and ultimately a csv of their properties for an index (name, date, size, length, format).

There are various tools to do this for single files, and I have seen some fixups such as using scripts of mediainfo in a .bat file, but none give a listing which can be imported as a table, or across multiple directories. Windows Explorer sill list all of this in visual format but not to a file, and I don't know of any way to coerce it to make a file of it. Also it only knows the lengths of certain video file types (mp3, mp4, asf, wmv), but not many others (flv, ...). Also Explorer is directory specific, and won't recurse like Dir can.

I'd be happy with any utility to do this, but lacking that would tend to try to do it in Python. Are there good library utilities for this in Python, or other suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`os.walk`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html) to walk through the directory tree.  [pymedia](http://pymedia.org/) is a library that may help with reading mp3, avi, and other formats.  So does [eye3D](http://eyed3.nicfit.net/).

Using os.walk is fairly easy:

```
import os

ROOT_DIR = '.'

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(ROOT_DIR):
    for f in files:
        # This takes the file with it's dir an does whatever you want
        analyze_file(f, root)
```

Comment: https://bitbucket.org/haypo/hachoir/wiki/hachoir-metadata  also handles most media files it looks like

Comment: Thanks; I know how to traverse the file system, video properties is the unknown to me. I'll check on pymedia.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the Python pointers. While that would be a more flexible solution, for my specific situation I found a tool "*exiftool*" which will do just what I want;

```
A:\VideoCam>exiftool -csv -FileName -FileSize -MIMEType -CreateDate  -d "%r %a, %B %e, %Y" -DateTimeOriginal -Duration -S -s -ImageSize *.vob  > data.csv
```